# WP Revolution slider not displaying properly 1 out of 5 times randomly

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I am having an issue with a website for our student-organized congress at http://ebspreneurship.de that randomly bugs roughly 1 ever 5 times - sometimes more, sometimes less.

I have three revolution sliders - one is the above-the-fold content (full screen), just under it is the Elements section with another full width revolution slider(RS) and then on the bottom I have this map.

From time to time randomly one of the 2 upper sliders (the last one never bugs) disappears and shows only the background image. I can't trace what's the problem, i spend a few days on that. I notice that if I start many browsers with the website and find one that's bugged, there is an error on Inspect:

```
Issue at YouTube Video Pause:
(unknown) TypeError: d.getPlayerState is not a function
```

Still,  tried without youtube video and it bugs the same way with only BG image, so that error is for now irrelevant.

I just don't get what's the problem and I tried disabling all plugins, i tried playing with caching methods or disabling it... Nothing changes it...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OK, for some reason on random intervals the page loads with my main layer div being with "visibility: hidden;", while the div of the image has "opacity: 0.0001."

So,i went for brute force solution of overriding all div's ids one by one on both sliders.

It worked, since, as seen in the image, the browser loaded with hidden divs and opacity 0.0001, but my override worked and still displayed correctly. [Image of how the bug was overridden and displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM32V.jpg)

Thank you for the ones that tried to help (I noticed quite a few good souls that as always are found around here)!!